# decode subprocess.Popen and store in file

Tags: python, subprocess, decode, encode, popen

I wrote a script / Addon for pyLoad.

Basically it executes FileBot with arguments.

What I am trying to do is to get the output and store it into the pyLoad Log file.

So far so good. It works until that point where a single character needs to be decoded.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I dont know how to do that.
I hope u guys can help.

```
    try:
        if self.getConfig('output_to_log') is True:
            log = open('Logs/log.txt', 'a')
            subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=log, stderr=log, bufsize=-1)
```

Thanks in advance

[edit]

```
28.05.2015 12:34:06 DEBUG     FileBot-Hook: MKV-Checkup (package_extracted)
28.05.2015 12:34:06 DEBUG     Hier sind keine Archive
28.05.2015 12:34:06 INFO      FileBot: executed
28.05.2015 12:34:06 INFO      FileBot: cleaning
Locking /usr/share/filebot/data/logs/amc.log
Done ヾ(＠⌒ー⌒＠)ノ
Parameter: exec = cd / && ./filebot.sh "{file}"
Parameter: clean = y
Parameter: skipExtract = y
Parameter: reportError = n
Parameter: storeReport = n
Parameter: artwork = n
Parameter: subtitles = de
Parameter: movieFormat = /mnt/HD/Medien/Movies/{n} ({y})/{n} ({y})
Parameter: seriesFormat = /mnt/HD/Medien/TV Shows/{n}/Season {s.pad(2)}/{n} - {s00e00} - {t}
Parameter: extras = n
```

So im guessing this

```
Done ヾ(＠⌒ー⌒＠)ノ
```

is causing the issue

when i open the loginterface on the webgui to see the log - this is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/pyload/module/lib/bottle.py", line 733, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/share/pyload/module/lib/bottle.py", line 1448, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "/usr/share/pyload/module/web/utils.py", line 113, in _view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/pyload/module/web/pyload_app.py", line 464, in logs
    [pre_processor])
  File "/usr/share/pyload/module/web/utils.py", line 30, in render_to_response
    return t.render(**args)
  File "/usr/share/pyload/module/lib/jinja2/environment.py", line 891, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/share/pyload/module/web/templates/Next/logs.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'Next/base.html' %}
  File "/usr/share/pyload/module/web/templates/Next/base.html", line 179, in top-level template code
    {% block content %}
  File "/usr/share/pyload/module/web/templates/Next/logs.html", line 30, in block "content"
    <tr><td class="logline">{{line.line}}</td><td>{{line.date}}</td><td class="loglevel">{{line.level}}</td><td>{{line.message}}</td></tr>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback so we know exactly which line throws the error?

Comment: Put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`  at the top of your Python script to see if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
        proc=subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        for line in proc.stdout:
            self.logInfo(line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n'))
        proc.wait()
```